# Using entity key to retrieve entries from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

My Datastore contains: an entry with an `id/Name id = 30001`

I tried: `SELECT * FROM Skill WHERE Id=30001` and a few other variations.
   How can i use the entity key to retrieve entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest and more convenient method to retrieve a Model by a given id is by calling the [get_by_id()](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id) class method of the Model:

```
skill = Skill.get_by_id(30001)
```

Using GQL is pretty much slower and it's achieved using `KEY`:

```
SELECT * FROM Skill WHERE __key__ = KEY('Skill',30001)
```